# JQuery Mobile clone page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, clone

I having trouble cloning a page of jqm. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QZKBw/

as you can see, the cloning and modifing the page is not the problem:

```
    var newPage = $('#page-1').clone();
    newPage.prop('id', 'page-2');
    newPage.find('#header-1')
        .prop('id', 'header-2')
        .find('h1')
        .html('Page 2');
```

The switch back to page 1 will end up with two active pages. Is it a problem with jqm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Nc98p/

```
$(function () {
    $('#clone-page').click(function () {
        if($('#page-2').length == 0){
            var newPage = $('#page-1').clone();
            newPage.prop('id', 'page-2');
            newPage.find('#header-1')
                .prop('id', 'header-2')
                .find('h1')
                .html('Page 2');
            newPage.find('#content-1')
                .prop('id', '#content-2')
                .html('<a href="#page-1" data-role="button"> to Page 1</a>');
            newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);        
        }        
        $.mobile.changePage('#page-2');
    });
});
```